# Get only the first item from NodeJS.ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fetch

I want to know if it's possible to get only first item from a readable stream in fetch response body without iterating through it.

The data comes as a raw string and looks something like this:

```
...
2023-11-28T00:00:00.0000000Z { "data": { ..., "p": "36966.01000000", ... } }
...
```

I can't just parse it with `JSON.parse()`, so I found a way to read stream like this:

```
import split from 'split2'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const response = await fetch(<url>, <options>)
const lines = response.body.pipe(split())
for await (const line of lines) {
    let value = parseFloat(JSON.parse(line.split(' ')[1]).data.p)
    break
}
```

This method involves passing through the lines of the pipe in `for...of` loop and breaking it after first iteration.

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to do it?